# How do I check if 1 is always followed by a 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary

In **Python**, I cannot find a solution as to how to determine whether there is always a 0 following a 1 somewhere in a list of numbers, to form a pair **10**. It doesn't have to be direct follower.

For clarity, I mean "list" as in (sort of) binary number, to be specific,

```
1100  #pass
1001  #fail
1010  #pass
0101  #fail

11110000  #pass
11100001  #fail

11100100  #pass
```

There must be always an equal number of 1es before 0es.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? can you share?

Comment: Try to think of the logic behind this setup. Make an attempt. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What do you mean **always** and **somewhere**, in the first case, the 1 is not **always** followed by a 0. Only the second case would pass the filter.

Comment: What about `if '10' in s` or `if '10' in bin(s)`

Comment: Only reasonable solution I have come up with was to compare values from the beginning and the end, until there is a match of 1 and 0, then remove both from the list and repeat.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky The 0 does not have to be a direct follower, right after a 1, it just has to be somewhere after a 1. For instance, 110 would fail, because there is a single 1 without a pair, same with 100. Also, 1100 passes, because you can get two pairs - 1**10**0 and **1**10**0**

Answer (score 0):

```
cases = ['0111', '1100','1001','1010','0101','11110000','11100001','11100100', '11100000', '11000110']

def check(s):
    cnt_0, cnt_1 = sum(ch == '0' for ch in s), sum(ch == '1' for ch in s)
    if cnt_0 != cnt_1:
        return False
    i1 = (v[0] for v in enumerate(s) if v[1] == '1')
    i2 = (v[0] for v in enumerate(s) if v[1] == '0')
    for idx1, idx2 in zip(i1, i2):
        if (idx2 < idx1):
            return False
    return True

for case in cases:
    print(case, check(case))
```

Prints:

```
0111 False
1100 True
1001 False
1010 True
0101 False
11110000 True
11100001 False
11100100 True
11100000 False
11000110 False
```

Comment: It doesn't work on many other cases though. For example, for 11100100 should return True, but it doesn't

Comment: @igor Why `11100100` returns `True`? At the end there's only one `1` followed by two `00`...

Comment: Because if you break it down, you get **1**110010**0**, 1**1**10**0**100, 11**10**0100 and finally 11100**10**0

Comment: Now 11100000 passed, even when it shouldn't :D I just cannot wrap my head around it, it seems so easy, yet I cannot come up with anything functional... Feel free to give it up, but thanks anyway

Comment: It's like a nightmare, there is just 11000110 left for some reason

Comment: @igor but `11000110` is `False`, no? **1**1**0**00110, then 1**1**0**0**0110, then 110**0**0**1**10 which is wrong and should be `False`. Do I get this correctly?

Comment: Hej, praveze to, lenze oto to vyhodnoti ako spravne z nejakeho dovodu... uz len na konci ked je 110 tak automaticky to musi byt zle

Comment: @igor English ;) I Updated my answer - As you see `11000110` returns `False` as it should...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203359/discussion-between-igor-and-andrej-kesely).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def is_good(n):
    n = n[2:]
    length = 0
    if re.search(r'.*1+$', n):
        return False;

    for i, b in enumerate(n):
        if b == '1':
            length += 1
        else:
            if len(n) - i < length:
                return False
            else:
                if length != 0:
                    if n[i:i + length] != '0' * length:
                        return False
                    length = 0
    return True


print((is_good('1b11100001')))
print((is_good('1b11100000')))
print((is_good('1b1100')))
print((is_good('1b1101')))
print((is_good('1b1010')))
print((is_good('1b0101')))
print((is_good('1b0111')))
```

Comment: Naming a function `len` is a bad idea. Why are you doing `n.__len__()`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution just uses nested for loops. No modules importation required :)

1 - Outer for loop to test each number in the list

2 - Inner for loop to test other numbers in the list with the number in the outer loop

```
binary = list("0100")
result = "Fail"


for idxNumber, number in enumerate(binary):
    for idxOtherNumbers, otherNumbers in enumerate(binary):
        if int(number) == 1:
            if int(otherNumbers) == 0 and idxOtherNumbers > idxNumber:
                result = "Pass"
            elif int(otherNumbers) == 1 and idxOtherNumbers > idxNumber:
                result = "Fail"
print(result)
```

Comment: Why all the casts using `int()`? Why convert that string to a list? Your `continue` statements seems unnecessary.

Comment: Using int() because list("0100") creates list of numbers in string format. Thanks for pointing out the continue statements. I fixed the code.

Comment: Yes, my point is that there is no reason to want a list of ints instead of a string. Your program doesn’t make use of the fact that they’re ints at all.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the advantage of converting to int is that the code now accepts a string or a list of ints.

Comment: @EricDuminil I hadn’t thought of that, I guess it’s a nice bonus.

Comment: @OYahya: You don't need nested loops though. One is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a temp variable, initialized at `0`. Increment it for each `1`, decrement it otherwise.
It should never be negative, and to make sure there are as many `1` as `0`, it should be equal to `0` at the end.

```
def check(bits):
    temp = 0
    for bit in bits:
        if temp < 0:
            return False
        if int(bit) == 1:
            temp += 1
        else:
            temp -= 1
    return temp == 0
```

As an example:

```
>>> check('1100')
True
>>> check('110001')
False
>>> check('1')
False
>>> check('10')
True
>>> check('1010')
True
>>> check('123')
False
```

Comment: How did you figure this out, by the way?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: I've been programming for 30 years. :D But mostly, it looks like a simpler version of determining if parens and brackets are [balanced](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/) : `{({})[](())}`. You need a stack for this, but since there's only one type of "bracket", you only need to know if the stack is empty or not. So you can replace the stack with a simple counter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a NumPy method, with accompanying utility function to convert the strings into arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

def nums_str_to_ndarr(str_in: str) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.fromiter(str_in, dtype=int, count=len(str_in))


def valid_ones_arr(nums_arr: np.ndarray) -> bool:
    nums_arr[nums_arr == 0] = -1
    nums_arr = np.cumsum(nums_arr)
    return np.all(nums_arr >= 0) and (nums_arr[-1] == 0)
```

I will be using it as a benchmark/standard while looking for a better solution. You are of course all welcome to do the same :)

Comment: @EricDuminil Tbh I thought I had made a few changes, but I might be thinking of a different function which didn’t pan out. Sorry D: